# codeigniter library with database connection

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder, codeigniter-library

I am creating a new custom library with database connection  but am unable to load the database

This is my custom library :

```
class Seo {
    var $CI;
    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');
        $this->CI->config->item('base_url');
        $this->CI->load->database();


    }
    public function getMetadata($pageid){
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('HHCL_PAGES AS A');
     $this->db->join('HHCL_META AS B','A.PAGE_ID = B.PAGE_ID','LEFT');
     $this->db->join('HHCL_META_OG AS C','A.PAGE_ID = C.PAGE_ID','LEFT');
     $this->db->where('A.PAGE_ID',$pageid);
     $data = $this->db->get->result();
     echo"<pre>";print_r($data);exit;
     $this->CI->load->view('home/layouts/header',$data); 
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
 A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice

    Message: Undefined property: Seo::$db

    Filename: libraries/Seo.php

    Line Number: 30

    Backtrace:

    File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hhcl\application\libraries\Seo.php
    Line: 30
    Function: _error_handler

    File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hhcl\application\controllers\Home.php
    Line: 28
    Function: getMetadata

    File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hhcl\index.php
    Line: 316
    Function: require_once
```

i have defined this library in auto load along with database and session, how can i over come this?

Comment: Change `$this->db->select('*');` to `$this->CI->db->select('*');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$this;` to `$this->CI;`

*Should be like this :*

```
public function getMetadata($pageid)
{
    $this->CI->db->select('*');
    $this->CI->db->from('HHCL_PAGES AS A');
    $this->CI->db->join('HHCL_META AS B','A.PAGE_ID = B.PAGE_ID','LEFT');
    $this->CI->db->join('HHCL_META_OG AS C','A.PAGE_ID = C.PAGE_ID','LEFT');
    $this->CI->db->where('A.PAGE_ID',$pageid);
    $data = $this->CI->db->get()->result();
    echo"<pre>";print_r($data);exit;
    $this->CI->load->view('home/layouts/header',$data); 
}
```

Comment: Call to a member function result() on null am getting this error @pradeep

Comment: getting this Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$get and Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\hhcl\application\libraries\Seo.php on line 35 errors

Comment: `get` should be `get() ` see my answer for that

Comment: pleasure is mine , happy coding